# How do I push the result of this complex command line grep statement to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, bash, grep, httrack

This code searches through website html files and extracts a list of domain names...

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)'
```

The result looks like this.

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com

I plan to use this code on very large websites, therefore this will generate a very large list of domain names.  In addition, the above code generates a lot of duplicate domain names.  Therefore, I setup a mysql database with a unique field so duplicates will not be inserted.

Using my limited knowledge of programming I hacked together this line below, but this is not working. When I execute the command, I get no error, just a new command prompt of > and a blinking cursor. I assume I'm not using the correct syntax or methodology, and/or maybe what I want to do is not possible via command line.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | domain=“$(grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)’)” | mysql -pPASSWORD -e "INSERT INTO domains.domains (domains) VALUES ($domain)”
```

And yes, my database name is domains, and my table name is domains, and my field name is domains.

Comment: Ok, will do, thanks...  When I execute the command, I get no error, just a new command prompt of > and a blinking cursor.

Comment: Not much to work with. I would organize the code a little different,to  create the `insert ....` statements just to echo to std-out. Then, worst case you can cut paste a block of them into a gui-editor. But first, have you done basic tests like `echo "select getdate()" | mysql -pPS -dDB` to confirm the most basic stuff works? (use what ever is the mysql equivalent for `getdate()`). And, yes, this shouldn't be problem to get working. Try searching here for small examples. Good luck.

Comment: Ok.  After your suggestion, I took out the mysql part for time being, and still just get a new command prompt upon execution.  Apparently, the problem may be with my attempt at setting of the domain variable..  httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" | domain=“$(grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)’)” | echo $domain  Any idea on what is wrong with this?

Comment: best to work like `echo "1_line_Sample_from_httrak_with_domain" | egrep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org\)'` until you get your regExp working. What you have seems like it should work. So also eliminate odd chars that might be throwing off grep with `tr -d '[:alnum:]-]' <smallTestFile > smallTestCleanFile`, or the above like `echo "1_line_Sample_from_httrak_with_domain" | tr -d '[:alnum:]-]' | egrep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org\)'`. Going out for the evening. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the MySQL syntax for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,…)] 
    [(col_name,…)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},…),(…),…
    …
```

you need to convert the domain names into parenthesized, quoted, comma separated items:

```
('domain1.com'),('domain2.com'),…
```

and then attach this list to the end of the INSERT statement you generated.

```
httrack --skeleton http://www.ilovefreestuff.com -V "cat \$0" |
grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.(com|net|org)’ |
sort -u |
sed -e "s/.*/,('&')/" -e '1s/,/INSERT IGNORE INTO domains.domains(domain) VALUES /' |
mysql -pPASSWORD
```

The `sort -u` ensures that the names are unique.  The first `-e` to `sed` converts the contents of a line (e.g. `domain1.com`) into `,('domain1.com)`; the second `-e` removes the comma of the first line (added by the first `-e`) and replaces it with the `INSERT` prefix.  The `IGNORE` in the `INSERT` statement means that if a domain is already in the table, the new entry will be ignored.

Clearly, if the number of domains generated is too large for a valid SQL statement in MySQL, you'll have to do some splitting of the data, but you're likely to be able to process a few thousand domains at a time.